# What's the connection between being homogeneous in energy and having a proper time scale?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, time

Towards the end of page 8 of [this scientific paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0210117v1), I have found the following sentence:

> ...given the fact that the system is homogeneous in energy, or equivalently, that it has no proper time scale.

I'm not sure about what the authors intend to say (what is the relation between being homogeneous in energy and having (or not) a proper time scale). I know the relationship of energy and time as conjugate variables in the formalism of quantum mechanics but this paper is about linear thermodynamics.

Comment: That phrase should be parsed *"proper time-scale"* (that is a correctly chosen characteristic time) not *"proper-time scale"* (i.e. a device that measures proper time, also known as a clock).

Comment: ok @dmckee, I agree, any idea about the meaning?

Comment: Perhaps it means that, since the energy has homogenized, that no further evolution is expected. So, no kinetic time scale (scattering, diffusion, etc) applies to system evolution.  Just a guess.